# Qr code reader lib for reading bar code only reads EAN13 format

Tags: codenameone

I have seen the QRcode reader library just patched by Steve(I'm very much grateful to Steve and cn1 team) but found out the following code. There is EAN13 type mentioned, so the bar reader only reads EAN13 bar code. I need to read the imei no. of mobile devices which is I think code_128 or may be code_39 format. So can you make the library read other formats of bar code too. Thankyou

```
    if (qrCode) {
        intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.QRCODE});
    } else {
        intent.putExtra(ZBarConstants.SCAN_MODES, new int[]{Symbol.EAN13});
    }
```

update 1:

```
    scanBarButton.addActionListener(e -> {
    Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "CODE_39;CODE_93;CODE_128");
    QRScanner.scanBarCode(new ScanResult() {
        public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
            imeiTextArea.setText(contents);
        }

        public void scanCanceled() {
            Dialog.show("Cancelled", "Scan Cancelled", "OK", null);
        }

        public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
            Dialog.show("Error", message, "OK", null);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "CODE_128");

Possible values include:

```
"UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128", "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED", "QR_CODE" & "DATA_MATRIX"
```

Notice you can support more than one type by separating it with semicolon e.g.:

```
Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "CODE_128;CODE_93");
```

Comment: I already tried that but it only reads EAN_13 which is set in the library code above. plz see the updated code above in the question...

Comment: here in the lil monkey QRScanner git -  https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner and its in the new patched lib by shannah too. https://github.com/shannah/QRScanner